# The numeric list types don't apply the correct font-family

Tags: css

I converted a design file, Figma to HTML&CSS. The problem is that the `ol` list types don't apply the correct font-family. I checked them from the inspect mode and they look like they have the correct font-family but they don't render it as expected way. What should I do? Thanks

Here are the project links:
[The Github repository](https://github.com/adonmez04/FEM-Recipe-page-v1)
[The project web page](https://adonmez04.github.io/FEM-Recipe-page-v1/)

Here's the correct ol list type:
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rtf0.png)

I have the same font-family for my `ol` elements, but they don't apply the font-family as expected.

```css
.section-instructions ol li::marker {
  color: var(--brandy-red, #854632);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

**Solved**

As @Leothelion mentioned, I've added this declaration to my code and it works as I expected:

```css
font: normal 700 1rem/1.5 "Outfit", "Arial", sans-serif;
```

The `::marker` pseudo-element selector only applies the shorthand `font` property to the style. I checked out the mdn page on `marker` and I thought it could accept the longhand versions of the `font` property, but it can't.

Here are some details about the `marker` pseudo-element selector:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

*Note: I opened this question about `ol`  list styles, but I used `::marker` pseudo-elements to style them. I really forgot about it and my title is not totally wrong.*

Comment: They look correct to me. Make sure you have emptied the cache.

Comment: You are applying Outfit/Arial.  That looks like what you got.  What were you expecting?

Comment: I have updated your git. Please check.

Comment: Please put relevant code direct into your question - an external site may disappear (or get corrected as done by @Leothelion) thus rendering your question useless to future readers.

Comment: @Leothelion thanks. I've added your update to my code and it works as I expected `font: normal 700 1rem/1.5 "Outfit", "Arial", sans-serif;`. It's weird because I have the same values this shorthand property for its longhand versions, but it couldn't apply them. I think the `ol` element only applies the `font` property to the style.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, it has the same font-family, but it doesn't look the same as the design file. That was my problem.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, you're right. I'll update my post.

Comment: Should i post it as solution or you are expecting another solution?

Comment: @adonmez04 also 1 point, if you dont want to apply css on marker as font then simply add font-variant :normal and you are good to go. Marker will inherit the css.

Comment: @Leothelion it's definitely the right solution. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Leothelion I've added the `font-variant: normal;` option to my code. It works too, and it's a good option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have checked there are 2 possible solution for apply css (font-family) to ol (marker) :

1. Add `font:normal 400 1rem/1.5 "Outfit", "Arial", sans-serif;` to .section-instructions ol li::marker class so your new class will look like this :

```css
.section-instructions ol li::marker {  
      color: var(--brandy-red, #854632);
      font:normal 400 1rem/1.5 "Outfit", "Arial", sans-serif;      
      font-size: inherit;      
      font-style: inherit;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
```

You can use `font` directly on marker.

2. If you want to inherit the property from body then simply use `font-family: inherit;` and you are good to go. Your updated class will be :

```css
    .section-instructions ol li::marker {
      color: var(--brandy-red, #854632);
      font-family: inherit;
      font-variant: normal;
      font-size: inherit;
      font-style: inherit;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
```

Hope this helps.